# xmlhttprequest status 0 statusText "unknown" - security certificate?

Tags: javascript, security, networking, xmlhttprequest

This is being done in javascript for IE: So I continue to do work with xmlhttprequest and I THOUGHT I finally understood how to use it well enough to use it in all cases.  Well I don't even know what to think when the status being returned is 0 and the statusText is "unknown".  So I create an XMLHttpRequest and push it onto an array, this particular one is in requests[0].  Here's the relevant code.

```
this.requests[0].open("GET", "https://" + this.address, true);
//This is just something I put in that I found that would supposedly 
//Fix the problem.
this.requests[0].setRequestHeader("Content-type", "text/xml");
this.requests[0].send();
function onReadyStateChange1() {
    if (4 == me.requests[0].readyState) {
        if (me.requests[0].status == 200) {
            //Once I get this working I'll have a statement to use          
            //XML for response if possible.
            var response = me.requests[0].responseText;
            return response;            
       }
    }
}
```

I can't seem to figure out why.  Can XMLHttpRequest simply somehow not handle secure http connections?  Or is it, as I believe is far more likely, that because there is a problem with the website's security certificate the XMLHttpRequest refuses to get it?  Or is it something else?

Comment: Well I went and found out that http and https domains cannot be in the same domain...  Meaning now I guess I need to circumvent that fact?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code in question is probably throwing a security exception.

Yes, the Protocol is a part of the Origin; you cannot make cross-origin requests with XMLHTTPRequest in IE. Try the XDomainRequest object instead.

Comment: Hi, I appreciate the answer. I actually found the XDomainRequest object when I was looking for things, and I tried it but I can't seem to actually open anything with it. I tried to open random pages, the page in the example Microsoft provides on MSDN, and also the actual addresses I'm going to be opening. However, I feel like part of the problem might be the lack of the necessary header server side? Maybe the examples should have worked though. Either way I'm not working on the server side so I can't add the header for what I actually need.  Any idea for why it might not be working?

Comment: To clarify, nothing actually works with the xdr.  I have the creation of it in an if (window.xDomainRequest) statement and it does get into that statement.  However, I can't do anything (even just set the content type to text/plain) without it breaking.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean "set the content type"-- XDomainRequest doesn't expose that capability. A working example of XDR can be seen here: http://www.fiddler2.com/test/xdr.asp